# User set in global.asax only available after next request

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, claims-based-identity

I am building an intranet application using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Windows authentication. In the global.asax file, I have implemented this method:

```
protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
```

In this method, I create a new `ClaimsIdentity` and set `args.User` to it, just like the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationmodule.authenticate(v=vs.110).aspx). Later on in the application, in one of the Controllers, I need to get some data from the database. Since I already had an API action that does this, I call that API (synchronously) from my Controller.

The API gets the claims for the current user using the [ApiController.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user(v=vs.118).aspx) property. Here though, the claims are not the ones I set in global.asax. In fact, they are the claims that were in place on the user before this request.

The strange thing (to me) is that the next time I make a call to the application, the new claims are in place. So in my case, I change the claims that later on decide which buttons should be visible to a user, but only after the user makes another request to the application, these buttons are updated.

How can I make sure that the claims that I set in global.asax immediately take effect?

#### Extra info:

I don't set the claims on every request. When this method executes, I check a number of things to see if the user is still valid: cookie, user isn't anonymous, and user is still "valid". The latter is decided by cache - I keep a list of users that are still valid and if someone updates their permissions through a user interface, they become invalidated and will receive new claims in their next request.

I've attached a debugger and I see my code getting executed, the principal gets all the claims I want it to have while still in this method. When I reach a controller action, `ApiController.User` has the claims it had on the request before this one. When I make another request, the authentication method is skipped (because the user name is now in the cache), and in the controller the `ApiController.User` has the correct claims.

Comment: try to fill the claims in this method Application_PostAuthenticateRequest

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both the members to make it work.

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access your claims in the same request that you set them. Try to redirect after setting your claims.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar. Here is my code, i hope it would be helpful.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clamisIdentityBuilder = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IClaimsIdentityBuilder>();
            var transformer = new ClaimsTransformer(clamisIdentityBuilder);
            var principal = transformer.Authenticate(string.Empty, ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

            // user if authenticated but Claims could not be created (they are not available in cache nor DB)
            if (principal == null)
            {
                var cacheProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICacheProvider>();
                cacheProvider.Clear();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Clear();
                string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl;
                Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
```